# Connecting the backgroundtap to storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am working with xCode 4.2 on its storyboard.

I am creating UITextFields, one with enter your name when the user clicks done, the keyboard disappears, the other UITextFieldenters your age when the user puts in the numbers and touches on the background the number pad disappears. But this one is not working.

With the previous xib, I used to connect the backgroundtap to the view but now with the storyboard I don't know how to connect it.

So, how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When Did End and Exit point to your Action

the action will resignFirstResponder.

2nd method is Click your View Then modified your Class which is UIView to UIControl
then TouchDown link to your backgroundTap Action.